# How can I add an image besides a textarea's line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, textarea

Imagine what Eclipse and other IDEs do when you have an error in your code. It goes something like:

> X itn number=5;

Where X is an image of a red circle with a white X for example. How could I produce such effect in a website? Taking into account that the textarea is scrollable.

Comment: I'd take the route of using a rich-text editor, something like TinyMCE. You would then be able to add your own styling to the text, whilst still allowing editing.

Comment: Your comment was a nice lead on. I ended up findind that TinyMCE was insufficient, due to it having a different focus, but that lead me onto ACE, which was precisely what I needed. ty.

Comment: Have you tried anything or if not then what you want to make that effect with ?

Comment: After finding ACE, I tried what I was going to do, and it worked. It had to do with "gutter functions". I'll elaborate on the answer editing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://ace.ajax.org/
Ace solved my need. It's a javascript augmented textarea with an emphasis on code editing.
BSD licensed.

(Edited after I found the ACE-way to do it)

By first setting up the editor as explained in the site, you then call either

A) Integrated way:

```
editor.getSession().setAnnotations([{row: lineNum, column: 0, html:"foo<br/>bar", type:"error"}]);
```

Where lineNum is 0-based (ie: 0 is the first line). There's also "warning" type, and both provide a default appropriate icon. There may be other types.

B) Hack version, or a more powerful way?, or The way that adds the css class of your liking:

```
editor.getSession().addGutterDecoration(0,"error_line");
```

Where 0 is the zero-based line number (ie : the first) and "error_line" is your own defined css class. You then use background-image: url(''); to choose the icon to use.
It's got other very sweet features like line number, and syntax highlighting for lots of commonly used languages.

Comment: Mark your answer as accepetd

Comment: Yeah, I know... but I can't until after 2 days. Sorry